# .NET MAUI Blazor Navigate to a specific page from MainActivity or pass url to MainPage.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, maui-blazor

I need to pass a string from for example `MainActivity.cs` to Razor components with `@page` tag.
I've read that in Xamarin there was a method called `LoadApplication(myString)` but it's not present in MAUI.
What I tried to do I use the Preferences Api like this

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Preferences.Set("key", "myString")
}
```

and then retrieve it where needed but it doesn't seem to be the best solution.
Basically I'm trying to implement deep linking and I need to navigate to a specific Razor page if the app is opened with such link. Not sure how you can navigate at this point of the app lifecycle. Can you maybe use the Shell for this in Blazor?

Comment: There's already [a thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/874348/documentation-example-missing-for-maui-x-blazor.html) on how to pass the value from `MainActivity.cs` to `Razor components` with @page tag. I think you can refer to it.